# why Can't I use the internet on mozilla?

Tags: mozilla

I've just installed the 14.04 ubuntu version and I the internet on mozilla was working, but now I can't use it.

I tried to restart the machine, but It hasn't worked so far.

Comment: What could I do to get more details my friend?

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you made any changes to the settings? Especifically, did you set up a proxy or changed the proxy settings?

You could - in a first step - ping a server like google (`ping www.google.com`) and check if you get any response, if so, it shows that your net is working and that it is the browser setting. If not you could try to ping google using its IP address... If that works, then the issue is most likly an issue with the DNS Servers (which are responsible for the resolution of the domain names).

Either way... it would help to have some more information on that one. You could - of course - also try to open the page with another browser and check if that works.

Hope that helps you.